# Setting up PostgreSQL on Mac OS 10.6.8 Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, postgresql

I've installed PostgreSQL 9 on Mac OS. I need to change the configuration so that I can access Postgre with the blank password. Searching online yields lots of solutions for older versions of the software, butt I don't know if they apply to the newer version. Many solutions discuss a `.conf` file of sorts, but the only config files are `.conf.sample` in the Postgre directories.

My root user now has a blank password. Having this blank password seems to result in an error when I try to connect or set a new password.

I recieve this when trying to connect with the empty password:

> psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

How can I change the password and/or enable the conf files?

Comment: enabling the config file should be as simple as removing the .sample extension and restarting the postgres server.

Answer (score 0):

Your PostgreSQL administrator account is most likely **postgres**. You can log in as postgresql administrator by first becoming *postgres* mac user `sudo -i -u postgres`. Then you can access PostgreSQL prompt with `psql`.

To change administrator password: `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'somepassword';`.

To allow logging in without password, you need to edit `pg_hba.conf`, which probably resides in`/Library/PostgreSQL/9.0/data/pg_hba.conf`.

I use *ident authentication* to allow mac user **jkj** to log in as PostgreSQL user **jkj** without password.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE  USER  CIDR-ADDRESS  METHOD
local   all       jkj                 ident
```

Remember that you first have to create your username in PostgreSQL. It can be a superuser.

```
createuser -s jkj
```

Comment: When trying to run psql, I am prompted for a password. The blank password returns `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`.